# jQuery clax not working where I add jQuery min.js

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

When I use jQuery clix then ajax is not working after when I use jQuery latest version then jQuery clix not work.

```
<script src="{{asset('build/js/custom.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery-calx-sample-2.2.8.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Any details re how exactly it "not work"? Error messages on your page? In JS console? Did you try latest stable 2.2.7 instead? Did you try older version of jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

j query calx actually not work latest jquery.min,js, if you use old less than  2 version that can do work. use this cdn i think solve your problem.

or if you face as like-`enter code here` jQuery tooltip and popover  not load and work
you can try this jquery  code:-

$('.hasTooltip').tooltip();

or say more details your actual problem.